# iptables and CONNMARK on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.04, multi-homed

How to enable connmark in netfilter in ubuntu 14. I see this post but I don't find the good module in Ubuntu 14.04.

I use connmark for multiwan. My configuration run perfectly in debian 8. But no connmark in ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the module on the kernel you can do:

```
modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

or

```
modprobe ip_conntrack
```

And to use **conntrack** you can install it like this(if using ubuntu):

```
apt-get install conntrack
```